# CiviCRM expert in India

Tags: civicrm-home

I'm representing an NGO based organisation in India. We have decided to move from paper based process to paperless process or at lease "less-paper".  We need an expert to implement CiviCRM in our organization. I couldn't find any Indian contacts in civicrm website , Can someone suggest an alternative solution to find an expert?

Answer (score 1):

I do think that the find expert page is the preferable way to find experts. If they are not on that page the question will arise how good they are in terms of involvement with the civicrm community.

If you want to find experts in India, you could best google it. 
There are some people in the community who are based in India. I do know that Harshal is based in India.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to find experts of CiviCRM.

1. [Find expert](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country_1=1101&services=All&language=All&cms=All) search from CiviCRM site.
2. Post a job on [freelancer](https://www.upwork.com/) sites
3. May be find an expert on https://chat.civicrm.org/

HTH

Pradeep